# In APUE 10.16, Why SIGINT is lost between the unblocking and the pause?

Tags: c

This is the sample code for APUE：

```
sigset_t newmask, oldmask;
sigemptyset(&newmask);
sigaddset(&newmask, SIGINT);
/* block SIGINT and save current signal mask */
if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask) < 0)
err_sys("SIG_BLOCK error");
/* critical region of code */
/* restore signal mask, which unblocks SIGINT */
if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL) < 0)
err_sys("SIG_SETMASK error");
/* window is open */
pause(); /* wait for signal to occur */
/* continue processing */
```

The book says that：To the application, this can look as if the signal occurs
between the unblocking and the pause (depending on how the kernel implements
signals). If this happens, or if the signal does occur between the unblocking and the pause, we have a problem. Any occurrence of the signal in this window of time is lost, in the sense that we might not see the signal again, in which case the pause will block indefinitely. This is another problem with the earlier unreliable signals.

I do not understand why SIGINT is lost between the unblocking and the pause?

Comment: The signal is not lost, it *can have been* handled by its signal handler, **before** pause() is entered, causing pause to block forever. (or at least until the *next* signal is delivered)  See `man 2 sigsuspend`

Comment: Understood, thank you @joop